# Boolean lattices vs boolean rings

Tags: ring-theory, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Which kinds of theorems about boolean algebras are easier to prove with boolean rings (than with actual boolean lattices)?

Give me at least one example, as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The size of any finite Boolean algebra is a power of $2$. This follows from the fact that any Boolean ring is an associative algebra over the field with two elements.

Comment: Thanks, but I am interested in **infinite** boolean lattices. I've forgotten to mention this in my question

Comment: What is the definition of the words "associative algebra" you use?

Comment: I am using this Wikipedia definition of [Associative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra), but actually, vector space suffices.